# How to show images uncropped after uploading?

Tags: images

[image]

As you can see, I've uploaded an image of book. Whenever I upload images, wordpress seems to crop it all the time. Is there a plugin or a code I can put to where it will show the whole picture instead of cropped ones?

Thank you very much in advanced!

Comment: This depends upon theme you are using. Theme may display cropped or original image.

Answer (score 0):

The theme you are using crops uploaded pictures, but there is always a version of the picture which keeps the original full size. Modify the code that render the picture that it will use the `size parameter`.
Eg:

```
Use: wp_get_attachment_image:
echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' );
Or: display post_thumbnail:
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'full' );

'full' here means the full size
```

More: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail